# Best practice for project with multiple related components

Tags: version-control, bug-tracking

Background: I'm using `jira` for bug tracking, and `git` for source control. I've got a complete end-to-end system comprising of an iOS front end, and a Java/Tomcat back end that provides web services and a GUI. Right now I've got a single git repository holding all the software and a single jira project tracking issues for the whole system.

Now that the software is live, I'm finding that changes are being made to either the iOS application or the server, but generally not both. The version numbers of the two components have diverged somewhat.

It's probably too late for this project, but in future:

- Should I pursue the path of having *all* related components in a single source repository and tracked using a single bug-tracking project; or
- Should each component be in a separate repository and be managed by a separate bug-tracking project?

I can see pro's and con's for both approaches, and I can also see that the answer could easily be "it depends".

Which way would you lean, and why?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with distinct source repositories for a few reasons

1. The developers working on the two are likely to have distinct
   skill sets.  Also, you may have management reasons for wanting to
   segregate who sees what.
2. They should not be tightly tied at a protocol level - different versions need to interact.
3. The first point becomes even more important when you do another front end

The second reason is my main one.

However, I'd go with a common bug database. Defects/features may need changes on both ends.  Also, it is extremely likely you will have bugs that are believed to be in one component but actually end up fixed in the other.   If you try to migrate across databases, information will get lost.  I've seen that too many times.

Comment: Jira is actually pretty good at moving bugs between projects, but point taken.